# ASP.NET - Get DIV width and set Table width

Tags: asp.net, html

I've got an ASP.NET, C# web app that has a DIV tag set to 100% so the contents of the div can expand or shorten based on the contents.  This works well but I'd like to modify it so that if the contents are below a certain width, then set the width to a standard width.  So this would eliminate the DIV tag looking really small for pages that only return a table with say 2 columns and not much data.

I set the ID and runat property of both the DIV and the table but when I try to get the width by clicking a button on the page, it always returns null:

```
<div id="content" runat="server">
   <table class="MainContent" width="100%" id="MainTable" runat="server">
        'data is in this table that could be 2 columns or 20, it's loaded 
        'dynamically in a gridview
   </table>
</div>
```

My button code:

```
string s = content.Attributes["width"];
```

How can I do this within my web app?  I. limited to using ASP.NET 2.0 and .NET 3.5 framework.

Comment: The server doesn't know the width of the div. That's determined on the client.

Comment: @JohnPick - Thanks...I did find a workaround with basic html: <div style="float:left; border: solid 1px red">
 <div style="margin-left: 10em; width:100%; border: solid 1px green">
  inner table/div
 <div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
min-width
```

**Definition and Usage**

*`The min-width property sets the minimum width of an element. Note: The min-width property does not include padding, borders, or margins!`*

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code in your codebehind...

```
<<div_name_here>>.Style.Add("property", "setting");
```

And for example

```
content.Style.Add("width", "600px");
```

CSS styles are supported.